# Redirect wrong URL/path DigitalOcean Spaces

Tags: digital-ocean, cdn, access-denied

I'm using Digital Ocean Spaces CDN to host a static website, so far so good, if I it my `index.html` everything is working as expected.

The problem I'm facing now, is that if the user hit any path which that is not `index.html` it gets back an Access Denied error.

I've looked inside the Digital Ocean Spaces CDN Settings and found nothing about redirecting on wrong url/path

Is there a way I could achieve that?

I would need a service like cloudflare in front of my CDN?

Sorry, but looking around on the web got me nowhere so far.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check a couple of things:

- You need to make all HTML files public
- Enable File Listing

DO Spaces does not support static page hosting (if someone visits your domain, you cant make redirection from "/" to "/index.html". IMO that's big no no. If you want free static hosting, just use https://www.netlify.com/  or git hosts (Github and Gitlab).