# Load index.html for every possible route of my React SPA that is hosted on digitalocean spaces

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

I use digital ocean space and CDN to host a React SPA. When hitting with a browser the url `[host]/index.html` it works fine. However hitting `[host]/index.html/customers/one` or any other subpaths, returns a 404. Currently, any reload on any subpath returns that 404. Last, I use terraform to update the SPA artifacts on DO spaces and I have tried to add a `website_redirect="/index.html"` to all the bucket objects (js, html and css) but with no success (more info if necessary [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/spaces_bucket_object#website_redirect)). And to be completely honest I am not sure I understand that option in the terraform digitalocean provider. I might be using it completely wrong.

Now, I have seen that question in multiple places but never with a clear answer.

- Here is one on digitalocean community (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/is-it-possible-to-send-a-301-redirect-for-bucket-objects) where no answer is provided but the issue seems to be similar.
- There is a similar question on SO without an approved answer [Redirect wrong URL/path DigitalOcean Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726289/redirect-wrong-url-path-digitalocean-spaces)
- This is a DO idea that is somewhat related https://ideas.digitalocean.com/ideas/DO-I-318

Is there a way to achieve the mentioned goal of loading index.html for every route with DO space + CDN and let the app parse the rest of the path to display the right component subtree of the react app?

Comment: `[host]/index.html/customers/one` is a strange-looking path. It's not supposed to be something more like `[host]/customers/1`?

Comment: Indeed but I believe it is the same issue with digitalocean spaces/CDN. My index.html file, the entrypoint is also on the CDN. I initially thought I could serve it when hitting the root path but that is not a feature implemented in DO it seems. I feel like I am not gonna avoid bootstrapping a new droplet and setting it up there.